# How to match string with database fields in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a database with a `name` column having data like

```
'Very big News'
'News'
'something else'
'New Nes'
'Fresh News'
'Something else'
```

Now given a string of words, how can I find if any of the words in the given string is contained in the `name` field?

For example:

I have a string `'super very news'`. I need to look in my database to see if I have any record such that the `name` field contains either `'super'` or `'very'` or `'news'` or `'super very'` or `'very news'`.

Comment: Did you try this?  Did it work?  What problems did you have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update** based on comments. See the query set docs [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
your_search_query = 'super very news'

qset = Q()
for term in your_search_query.split():
    qset |= Q(name__contains=term)

matching_results = YourModel.objects.filter(qset)
```

This creates the equivalent of:

```
matching_result = YourModel.objects.filter(Q(name__contains='super') |
                                           Q(name__contains='very') |   
                                           Q(name__contains='news'))
```

which produces (roughly) the following SQL in a single query:

```
 select * from your_model where name like '%super%' or name like '%very%' or name like '%news%'
```

Comment: No. You did not understand. I want to look not in remote database.
I want to look in my database if i have data which is inside string for example 'news about something' i need look if i have field 'news' or 'about' or 'something'

Comment: You want to do the search in your database model that holds the remote data.

Comment: i think he wants to do a `LIKE *news*` search -- keyword within a string -- but within any of the fields, not just one...

Comment: Yes! You right How can I do it wittout making request for every word?

Comment: No! No LIKE *news*. I have string 'super very news' I need look in my database if i have name field which contain word 'super' or 'very' or new' or 'super very' or 'very news'. Got it?

Comment: Yes! But it is pretty difficult for me.

Comment: I cant even imagin how it could be implement in SQL.

Comment: @Pol:  Which part is difficult?  Do you need more explanation on what's going on in my answer?

Comment: In real it will make few request to database?

Comment: @Pol: I've updated the answer with some more info. Also, I'd read through the link I provided at the top for more information.

Comment: You are the man. I could spend 1 day to find out how it work. Now I understend it totaly. If I could get book writen by you about django :)

Answer (score 0):

If your word list is small and simple you can write your own lookup table and indexer, otherwise you want a full text database like OpenFTS:

http://openfts.sourceforge.net/